# How do I stop a website from overriding my keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: firefox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, website

The [DeepL website](https://www.deepl.com/translator) has recently overridden my keyboard shortcuts so I can no longer copy paste sentences in and out of the text input boxes.

This still works if the keyboard is set to the US default. However when set to Dvorak, it changes `ctrl-c` to *Italicize* the words instead of copying them. `ctrl-v` is also borked in a unique and <sub>different way.</sub>

I've tried `permissions.default.shortcuts` in firefox to disable or prompt, but it has no effect here.

Comment: Do you mean that this is changed in other websites than DeepL? Check in `about:addons` if you have installed some DeepL extension.

Comment: If it's just on that site see https://superuser.com/questions/1132655/how-to-disable-block-suppress-a-specific-javascript-without-disabling-js

Comment: It's just on that website.